# Does dynamodb guarantee the sort order of a query on a global secondary index?

Tags: database, amazon-dynamodb

I am running queries on a global secondary index in dynamodb. In my index I have a hash key of "responseSetID" and a range key of "recordedDate". Since it is a GSI there can be multiple entries with the same recorded date in a response set. I know if I query by the hash and range key that the order is guaranteed by the recorded date, but what if I have 2 or more items that share the same recorded date? Will items that share the same range key be returned in a guaranteed order as well?